# Python slice operation

Tags: python

Could someone explain why the below slicing works?

```
>>> S='SPAM'
>>> S[1:1]
   ''
```

Comment: Could you explain why it shouldn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because selecting an empty slice is legal.

You can even select nonsensical slices:

```
>>> 'foo'[1:0]
''
```

Comment: Isn't the above stmt should retrieve -"give me everything from offset 1 up to but not includindg offset 1?

Comment: @user1050619: Indeed, which is the empty string.

Comment: @user1050619 yes - and in your own phrasing - haven't you just worked out why you get `''`? (*think about the* **not including** *bit*)

Comment: @user1050619 please quit trying to shorthand your expressions. This isn't twitter. You have lots of room to type an extra 6 characters. We're not u83r e1337 h4x0r5 here. We treat this like a professional development site. Please join us in using longer words, and more complete sentences. Even if this is your second language, the extra effort is noticed.

Comment: @user1050619 as this is the only and correct answer you're likely to get - it would be nice if you accepted it :)

Comment: Thanks guys.. I will give more information from my next question